# In Ruby, how to write a method to display any object's instance variable names and its values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, instance-variables

Given any object in Ruby (on Rails), how can I write a method so that it will display that object's instance variable names and its values, like this:

```
@x: 1
@y: 2
@link_to_point: #<Point:0x10031b298 @y=20, @x=38>
```

(**Update:** `inspect` will do except for large object it is difficult to break down the variables from the 200 lines of output, like in Rails, when you `request.inspect` or `self.inspect` in the ActionView object)

I also want to be able to print `<br>` to the end of each instance variable's value so as to print them out nicely on a webpage.

the difficulty now seems to be that not every instance variable has an accessor, so it can't be called with  obj.send(var_name)

(the var_name has the "@" removed, so "@x" becomes "x")

**Update:** I suppose using recursion, it can print out a more advanced version:

```
#<Point:0x10031b462>
    @x: 1
    @y: 2
    @link_to_point: #<Point:0x10031b298>
        @x=38
        @y=20
```

Comment: You could use the `inspect` method to do this if that is your question. Maybe it will be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see... Antal must be giving the advanced version here...

the short version then probably is:

```
def p_each(obj)
  obj.instance_variables.each do |v|
    puts "#{v}: #{obj.instance_variable_get(v)}\n"
  end
  nil
end
```

or to return it as a string:

```
def sp_each(obj)
  s = ""
  obj.instance_variables.each do |v|
    s += "#{v}: #{obj.instance_variable_get(v)}\n"
  end
  s
end
```

or shorter:

```
def sp_each(obj)
  obj.instance_variables.map {|v| "#{v}: #{obj.instance_variable_get(v)}\n"}.join
end
```

Comment: That's the bare-bones simplest form, yeah.  My solution also (a) recurses, so you get the tree structure, and (b) allows you to add the `<br />`s without rewriting the rest of your code.

Answer (score 6):

I would probably write it like this:

```
class Object
  def all_variables(root=true)
    vars = {}
    self.instance_variables.each do |var|
      ivar = self.instance_variable_get(var)
      vars[var] = [ivar, ivar.all_variables(false)]
    end
    root ? [self, vars] : vars
  end
end

def string_variables(vars, lb="\n", indent="\t", current_indent="")
  out             = "#{vars[0].inspect}#{lb}"
  current_indent += indent
  out            += vars[1].map do |var, ivar|
                      ivstr = string_variables(ivar, lb, indent, current_indent)
                      "#{current_indent}#{var}: #{ivstr}"
                    end.join
  return out
end

def inspect_variables(obj, lb="\n", indent="\t", current_indent="")
  string_variables(obj.all_variables, lb, indent, current_indent)
end
```

The `Object#all_variables` method produces an array containing (0) the given object and (1) a hash mapping instance variable names to arrays containing (0) the instance variable and (1) a hash mapping….  Thus, it gives you a nice recursive structure.  The `string_variables` function prints out that hash nicely; `inspect_variables` is just a convenience wrapper.  Thus, `print inspect_variables(foo)` gives you a newline-separated option, and `print inspect_variables(foo, "<br />\n")` gives you the version with HTML line breaks.  If you want to specify the indent, you can do that too: `print inspect_variables(foo, "\n", "|---")` produces a (useless) faux-tree format instead of tab-based indenting.

<del>There ought to be a sensible way to write an `each_variable` function to which you provide a callback (which wouldn't have to allocate the intermediate storage); I'll edit this answer to include it if I think of something.</del>  **Edit 1:** I thought of something.

Here's another way to write it, which I think is slightly nicer:

```
class Object
  def each_variable(name=nil, depth=0, parent=nil, &block)
    yield name, self, depth, parent
    self.instance_variables.each do |var|
      self.instance_variable_get(var).each_variable(var, depth+1, self, &block)
    end
  end
end

def inspect_variables(obj, nl="\n", indent="\t", sep=': ')
  out = ''
  obj.each_variable do |name, var, depth, _parent|
    out += [indent*depth, name, name ? sep : '', var.inspect, nl].join
  end
  return out
end
```

The `Object#each_variable` method takes a number of optional arguments, which are not designed to be specified by the user; instead, they are used by the recursion to maintain state.  The given block is passed (a) the name of the instance variable, or `nil` if the variable is the root of the recursion; (b) the variable; (c) the depth to which the recursion has descended; and (d), the parent of the current variable, or `nil` if said variable is the root of the recursion.  The recursion is depth-first.  The `inspect_variables` function uses this to build up a string.  The `obj` argument is the object to iterate through; `nl` is the line separator; `indent` is the indentation to be applied at each level; and `sep` separates the name and the value.

**Edit 2:** This doesn't really add anything to the answer to your question, but: just to prove that we haven't lost anything in the reimplementation, here's a reimplementation of `all_variables` in terms of `each_variables`.

```
def all_variables(obj)
  cur_depth = 0
  root      = [obj, {}]

  tree      = root
  parents   = []
  prev      = root

  obj.each_variable do |name, var, depth, _parent|
    next unless name

    case depth <=> cur_depth
      when -1 # We've gone back up
        tree = parents.pop(cur_depth - depth)[0]
      when +1 # We've gone down
        parents << tree
        tree = prev
      else # We're at the same level
        # Do nothing
    end

    cur_depth            = depth
    prev = tree[1][name] = [var, {}]
  end

  return root
end
```

I feel like it ought to be shorter, but that may not be possible; because we don't have the recursion now, we have to maintain the stack explicitly (in `parents`).  But it is possible, so the `each_variable` method works just as well (and I think it's a little nicer).

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick adaptation of a simple [JSON emitter I wrote for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015972/my-ruby-code-how-can-i-improve-java-to-ruby-guy/3016617#3016617):

```
class Object
  def inspect!(indent=0)
    return inspect if instance_variables.empty?
    "#<#{self.class}:0x#{object_id.to_s(16)}\n#{'  ' * indent+=1}#{
      instance_variables.map {|var|
        "#{var}: #{instance_variable_get(var).inspect!(indent)}"
      }.join("\n#{'  ' * indent}")
    }\n#{'  ' * indent-=1}>"
  end
end

class Array
  def inspect!(indent=0)
    return '[]' if empty?
    "[\n#{'  ' * indent+=1}#{
      map {|el| el.inspect!(indent) }.join(",\n#{'  ' * indent}")
    }\n#{'  ' * indent-=1}]"
  end
end

class Hash
  def inspect!(indent=0)
    return '{}' if empty?
    "{\n#{'  ' * indent+=1}#{
      map {|k, v|
        "#{k.inspect!(indent)} => #{v.inspect!(indent)}"
      }.join(",\n#{'  ' * indent}")
    }\n#{'  ' * indent-=1}}"
  end
end
```

That's all the magic, really. Now we only need some simple defaults for some types where a full-on inspect doesn't really make sense (`nil`, `false`, `true`, numbers, etc.):

```
module InspectBang
  def inspect!(indent=0)
    inspect
  end
end

[Numeric, Symbol, NilClass, TrueClass, FalseClass, String].each do |klass|
  klass.send :include, InspectBang
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
# Get the instance variables of an object
d = Date.new
d.instance_variables.each{|i| puts i + "<br />"}
```

[Ruby Documentation on instance_variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.src/M000366.html).

The concept is commonly called "introspection", (to look into oneself).

Comment: this only prints out the variable names, not the values

Comment: @Justin, or avoid `eval` and use `instance_variable_get`